# SpriteKit: Making stickman bounce

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm still super noob in spritekit and trying to get some tutorials here and there..

I'm trying to have stickman figure like this 
[image: stickman]
To jump of a high building and bounce when hit the ground node

It works fine when the node is ball with physicsbody of circle

But when trying physics body of rectangle .. it never bounce.. I've even tried this snipt of code

```
SKSpriteNode * victim = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"victim_base"];
    victim.position = CGPointMake(5, 500);
    victim.zPosition = 2;
    victim.name = @"victim";
    victim.xScale=0.7;
    victim.yScale=0.7;
    [self addChild:victim];

    CGFloat offsetX = victim.frame.size.width * victim.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = victim.frame.size.height * victim.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 13 - offsetX, 59 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 43 - offsetX, 58 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 38 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 7 - offsetX, 3 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    victim.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
    victim.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    // 4
    victim.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
    // 5
    victim.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
    // 6
    victim.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;

    [victim.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(10.0f, -10.0f)];
```

And setup of the gravity world is

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
// 1 Create an physics body that borders the screen
SKPhysicsBody* borderBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
// 2 Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
self.physicsBody = borderBody;
// 3 Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
```

but he is jumping and just stay still on the ground with no bouncing

I really can't figure what is the wrong here.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: set scene.showsPhysics = TRUE to render the physicsBodies on the screen. You can check how the physicsbody is coming out to be.

Comment: why did you switch off the gravity? Try to check out the `self.frame` value when setting the `self.physicsBody` property.

Comment: i'm switching it off according to this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/49721/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-using-spritekit
to make him bounce forever

Comment: From your description above, I'm guessing that the tutorial you've provided a link to is not what you want to do....In there the physics is more like space physics, without any gravity, so you couldn't get the effect of a stick-man on earth bouncing after a jump. try not to set gravity to 0,0 and play with the impulse you apply to the stick-man, and try setting the y value to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

check out this sample

```
#import "milkhuntMyScene.h"

@implementation milkhuntMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

        myLabel.text = @"";
        myLabel.fontSize = 30;
        myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                       CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        [self addChild:myLabel];
        self.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsWorld.gravity=CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.8);

        SKSpriteNode *node=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dummy"];
        node.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(node.size.width, node.size.height)];
        node.position=CGPointMake(200, 50);
        node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=FALSE;
        node.physicsBody.dynamic=TRUE;
        node.physicsBody.restitution=1;
        node.physicsBody.allowsRotation=FALSE;
        node.physicsBody.mass=9999999;

        [self addChild:node];

    }
    return self;
}
//




//
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite.xScale=sprite.yScale=0.5;
        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation=FALSE;
        sprite.physicsBody.restitution=1.0;
          sprite.physicsBody.angularDamping=0.0;
        sprite.physicsBody.linearDamping=0.0;
      //  SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];

        //[sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        sprite.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height)];
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```